# DocuSign | Anchor Tags

Tags: json, docusignapi

If we are to define an anchor tags and want it to be invisible, I know we can just copy the background as the guide says (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/). But, is anyone familiar, what if the anchor tags \test\ is in two different colors? Can we cater that?

Or the options are to:

1. Trim the anchor tags.
2. Move the anchor tags in one color and just use xoffset/yoffset?

Answer (score 1):

Font color has no bearing on searching for the anchor text and processing tab placement.